# Why does first argument of `Function` deny parentheses?

Tags: javascript

To create this function dynamically,

```
var foo = function(argument = myFunc()){
    return argument
}
```

I wrote this code.

```
var funcArgument = "argument = myFunc()"
var funcBody = "return argument"
var foo = Function(funcArgument, funcBody)
```

However, I got a following error.

`Function arg string contains parenthesis`

Why does this limitation exist?

In order to avoid this limitation, it can be written as follows, but it is too tricky and is not preferable.

````
var funcArgument = "argument = Function`return myFunc\\u0028\\u0029```"
var funcBody = "return argument"
var foo = Function(funcArgument, funcBody)
````

Comment: Why don't you simply check `arguments.length` or `argument == null`? Looks like you are making things more difficult than they need to be.

Comment: The arguments to the Function constructor (not including the *last* argument) must be strings containing valid JavaScript identifiers. That's the way the thing works. Why do you have to create the function that way?

Comment: What is `argument = myFunc()`JavaScript has no default function parameter values and even if it had you can't simply call a function in the parameter list!? Maybe I'm just confused but what is it you#re trying to do here?

Comment: @xander in ES2015 it's possible to assign default values to function parameters with that syntax.

Comment: I'd avoid using the `Function` constructor, but you could do: `(new Function('return function(argument = myFunc()) { return argument }'))()`

Comment: I had tried creating function with keeping same format. I decide to check and assign default value in function body. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does this limitation exist?

There's no good reason, this should work according to the spec. In fact it *does* work in Firefox.

There's [an open bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=4230) for V8.